# Maven: automatically update only some libraries to their latest version

Tags: maven

I have created a parent pom project and some libraries that I manage.
So, for example:

```
<parent>
   <groupId>my.group</groupId>
   <artifactId>parent</artifactId>
   <version>1.2.3-SNAPSHOT</version>
</parent>

  <dependencies>
       ...a loooot of them
         <dependency>
               <groupId>my.group</groupId>
               <artifactId>lib</artifactId>
              <version>1.2.3-SNAPSHOT</version>
         </dependency>
       ..otheeeeers
  </dependencies>
```

Now, I'd like to always use the latest release or snapshot depending I'm on the develop or release branch.
Problem is that the "new" maven 3 approach only has:

```
mvn versions:use-latest-releases //release
mvn versions:use-latest-versions //snapshot
```

But this would update every other dependency and I don't want this! I just want to update the ones having groupId my.group.

Is this possible?

**edit:**

Following khmarbaise advice I'm using:

> mvn versions:use-latest-versions "-Dincludes=com.project.my:*:*:*:*"

But it seems that it only works for non-snapshot versions.
ie. If I define 0.0.2 version of my lib it works, while 0.0.2-SNAPSHOT is not seen..is this normal?

Another thing I noticed is that it only works for inline properties, for example this will not work:

```
<my-lib.version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</my-lib.version>

<groupId>com.project.my</groupId>
<artifactId>mylib</artifactId>
<version>${my-lib.version}</version> <--- undetected, I need to put 0.0.1-SNAPSHOT explicitely
```

Comment: I would recommend to take a look into the docs: https://www.mojohaus.org/versions-maven-plugin/use-latest-releases-mojo.html#includesList

Answer (score 0):

Following the advice of khmarbaise, just call something like

```
mvn versions:use-latest-releases -Dincludes=mygroup:*:*:*:*
```

Comment: Doesn't seem to work: my pom is not updating even though the command gives ok

Comment: Maybe you misspelled the groupId or some other parts of the `includes`?

Comment: Maybe it's the fact I'm using a powershell? Here's the command: mvn versions:use-latest-versions "-Dincludes=com.group.my:my-parent:*:*:*"

Comment: The dependency you want to update is called `my-parent`? Or this the name of your own POM?

Comment: artifact id my-parent, it's the parent pom of my project

Comment: So do you want to update your parent POM or your dependencies?

Comment: I don't know whether this works for parents. For parents, there is `versions:update-parent`. For the lib, it cannot work if you set the artifactId to `my-parent`.

Comment: Mmm...maybe I understood, updating issue

Comment: For properties you need https://www.mojohaus.org/versions-maven-plugin/update-properties-mojo.html